# Angular JS infinite loop on checkbox ng-click with $http request

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, rest, checkbox

I have a problem with infinite loop on $http request. Somehow it goes to infinite only on checkbox, because I`m changing the model value of variable, attached to this checkbox. Here is the code:

```html
<div ng-repeat="contract in contracts">
      <select ng-model="contract.name" ng-change="getTransliteratedMessage()"/>
      <div ng-repeat="additionalContract in contract.additionalContracts">
          <input type="text" ng-model="additionalContract.name"/>
          <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" ng-model="additionalContract.isMessage" ng-click="getTransliteratedMessage()"/>
          <label for="myCheckbox">Some msg</label>
      </div>
</div>
<textarea ng-model="transliteratedText"/>
```

and here is controller method:

```js
$scope.getTransliteratedMessage = function() {
   var transliterationPromises = [];
   angular.forEach($scope.contracts, function(contract) {
       transliterationPromises.push($http({method: 'GET', url: 'some/url', params: contract.name});
       angular.forEach(contract.additionalContracts, function(addContract) {
           if (addContract.isMessage) {
                transliterationPromises.push($http({method: 'GET', url: 'some/url', params: addContract.name});
           }
       });
   });
   $q.all(transliterationPromises).then(function(results) {
       angular.forEach(results, function(result) {
           $scope.transliteratedText = $scope.transliteratedText + ' ' + result.data;
       }
   }
}
```

So, here is the problem - when I change the first contract < select > element - it completes the transliteration method perfectly. But when I click on checkBox of additionalContract - it goes to infinite loop. I tried workaround with $timeout - didn't help, tried to prevent double-click with label problem - didn't help. There is some solution to this $rootScope.$apply which is being fired on each $http request. Maybe you can help?

Comment: Im not really sure and your code is a bit confusing, but my first guess would be that every checkbox generated by your ng-repeat has the same model and therefor your foreach is looping through the additional Contracts and everytime it pushes the http request in for every checkbox so by clicking 1 checkbox you actually change all but this is just a guess im not really sure

Comment: Done with only one checkbox - still there is a problem

Comment: then im not really sure just use some console.logs to figure out where the loop happens and the only thing i see in your code is that you are missing some ) after the forEach

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem was with the incorrect calling of function on some other place, which I thought was not necessary. I was sending function as a parameter, like

```
<my-directive my-attribute="getTransliteratedMessage()" .../>
```

But I needed to send it without parentheses (my-attribute="getTransliteratedMessage")

Sorry for stupid question, hope this will help someone in future.